# How does NSFetchedResultsController know what selected range of row to read from CoreData instead of reading entire all rows?

Tags: ios, swift

My understanding on `NSFetchedResultsController` is that, it will not load entire all rows from CoreData at once.

Based on the current visible UI table row on screen, `NSFetchedResultsController` will just load a small amount of rows, just to be good enough to be shown on screen.

But, when I try to read and test the official code from Apple, this is contrast with my perception.

https://github.com/yccheok/earthquakes-WWDC20/blob/master/LoadingAndDisplayingALargeDataFeed/Earthquakes_iOS/QuakesViewController.swift#L123

There are around 10,000++ items in the CoreData database.

When the app is started for the 1st time, `UITableView` is not being scrolled yet, and the following function being executed for the 1st time

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    var count = dataProvider.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects?.count ?? 0
    print(">>> SIZE \(count)")
    
    // Try to inspect the content...
    var quake = dataProvider.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects?[count-1]
    print("----> \(quake?.place)")
    return count
}
```

When setting up `NSFetchedResultController`, I also try to change the batch size explicitly to 1, just to see what is the outcome - https://github.com/yccheok/earthquakes-WWDC20/blob/master/LoadingAndDisplayingALargeDataFeed/Shared/QuakesProvider.swift#L284

```
/**
 A fetched results controller to fetch Quake records sorted by time.
 */
lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Quake> = {
    
    // Create a fetch request for the Quake entity sorted by time.
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Quake>(entityName: "Quake")
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "time", ascending: false)]
    fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = ["magnitude", "place", "time"]
            
    // Just for testing purpose to avoid NSFetchedResultsController
    // load all data at once into memory.
    fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 1

    // Create a fetched results controller and set its fetch request, context, and delegate.
    let controller = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest,
                                                managedObjectContext: persistentContainer.viewContext,
                                                sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    controller.delegate = fetchedResultsControllerDelegate
    
    // Perform the fetch.
    do {
        try controller.performFetch()
    } catch {
        fatalError("Unresolved error \(error)")
    }
    
    return controller
}()
```

---

When app launched for first time, the following outcome is printed

```
>>> SIZE 10902
----> Optional("43 km E of Teller, Alaska")
```

My questions are

1. Currently, there are only less than 20 visible UI table row shown on screen. But, it seems like CoreData has already load all 10,000++ rows at once? Is this an expected behaviour for `NSFetchedResultsController`. As, my understanding is having `NSFetchedResultsController`, is to avoid having to load all unnecessary data into memory in 1 time.
2. I do not see a way, on how `UITableView` communicate back to `NSFetchedResultsController` regarding the visible UI row range. Isn't `UITableView` suppose to tell `NSFetchedResultsController` that "Currently, UI row 0th till 14th are visible on screen. Please only load data in range 0th till 14th from CoreData database"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mistaken in your understanding of `NSFetchedResultsController` and its purpose.  It makes it easier to use Core Data with table views, particularly where objects are inserted, deleted or updated; You can use delegate methods to efficiently handle these actions without needing to reload the entire table view.

That said, there is a default behaviour of Core Data that means, in effect, only visible rows are loaded into memory regardless of whether you use an `NSFetchedResultsController` or not.

The default behaviour of Core Data is to only provide *fault* objects at first; A fault is a lightweight representation of an object.  When a property of the object is accessed Core Data fetches the full object from the persistent store and loads it into memory.

This may have the effect of only loading full objects for on-screen rows since `cellForRow(at:)` is only called for visible rows (plus a few extra to allow for scrolling).  If the only access to your fetched objects is in that function, then the faults will only fire for those rows.

As more rows become visible, cells will be required and more faults will fire, loading more data.

You can disable this faulting behaviour but it will increase memory use.

You can use [`UItableViewDataSourcePrefetching`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasourceprefetching) to fire faults ahead of display, but in many cases you won't see a difference in the UI.